# ZF2 How to set <input type='radio' CHECKED> with a custom Form Element

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, checked, custom-element

How do I set **checked** within a form input radio field?  This form field is added using a custom Form Element.  The value of this field isn't consistent.

My custom Form Element returns 1 element.  It is a radio input field.  I need this checked each and every time the form is submitted.  The reason I am using this instead of a "hidden" field is for the user to see this settings.

This is the custom Form Element

```
namespace Member\Form\Element;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Zend\Form\Element\Radio;

/**
* Class OriginalLanguageIsoRadio
*
* @package Member\Form\Element
*/
class OriginalLanguageIsoRadio extends Radio
{
   /**
    * @var EntityManager $entityManager
    */
   protected $entityManager;

   /**
    * @var string $translationKey
    */
   protected $translationKey;

   /**
    * @var string $textDomain
    */
   protected $textDomain;

   /**
    * @param EntityManager $entityManager
    * @param string $translationKey
    * @param string $textDomain
    */
   public function __construct(
       EntityManager $entityManager,
       $translationKey,
       $textDomain
   )
   {
       $this->entityManager = $entityManager;

       $this->translationKey = $translationKey;

       $this->textDomain = $textDomain;
   }

   /**
    * Get Value Options
    *
    * @return array
    *
    * @throws \Exception
    */
   public function getValueOptions()
   {
       $array = [];

       $query = $this->entityManager
           ->createQueryBuilder()
           ->from(
               'AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\TranslationsMasters',
               't'
           )
           ->select('t.languageIso')
           ->setMaxResults(1);

       $result = $query->getQuery()
                       ->getArrayResult();

       if (is_array($result) && count($result) > '0') {
           foreach ($result AS $value) {
               if ( $value['languageIso'] == '' ) {
                   $array['Global'] = $value['Global'];
               } else {
                   $array[$value['languageIso']] = $value['languageIso'];
               }
           }
       }

       return $array;
   }
```

}

Then I call the custom Form Element:

```
/**
 * Original Language Iso
 */
$this->add(
    [
        'type'       => 'Member\Form\Element\OriginalLanguageIsoRadio',
        'name'       => 'original_language_iso',
        'options'    => [
            'label' => 'original_language_iso'
        ],
        'attributes' => [
            'id' => 'original_language_iso',
        ]
    ]
);
```

This adds the following to my form:

```
<input type="radio" name="original_language_iso" id="original_language_iso" value="en-US">
```

My desired output is

```
<input type="radio" name="original_language_iso" id="original_language_iso" value="en-US" **checked**>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:
a) Backend:
The attributes array must contain a 'value' set to the only element of the values available, that's the way to auto-check the radio input. With your example, it would be:

```
$this->add(
    [
        'type'       => 'Member\Form\Element\OriginalLanguageIsoRadio',
        'name'       => 'original_language_iso',
        'options'    => [
            'label' => 'original_language_iso'
        ],
        'attributes' => [
            'id' => 'original_language_iso',
            'value'=>'something_here'
        ]
    ]
);
```

b) Front: 
Use jQuery to check the radio input. You may do it with:

```
jQuery('#original_language_iso').attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: I like option "a".  But how do I set the "value" field with a database query?

Comment: Previous to the building of the whole form, you should query against the database to obtain the value you need. Then you may pass that value to the form constructor to update a private attribute (in this case original_language_iso_value for example), from that moment it would be available for any method inside the class, so you call set the value like "value"=>$this->original_language_iso_value